# Not getting proper output in Arduino (if statement)

Tags: arduino

This code is for decode morse code into text, but i am getting blank output

```
void Morse_decode()
{
  static String morse[] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....",
                             "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-",
                             ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "!"
                            };
  int i = 0;
  while (morse[i] != "!")  
  { 
    code = Serial.readString();
      //Serial.print(code);
    if (morse[i] == code)
    {
      Serial.print(char('A' + i));
      Serial.print(" ");
      break;
    }
      i++;
  }
```

this line is for reading the serial monitor input

```
 code = Serial.readString();
```

And in **if condition** i write **morse[i] == code** then its give not proper(blank) output,
What is my mistake?

but if i write specifically **"...."** or anything from **morse[] array** like morse[i] == "...."
in this case its give proper output **H**,
what should I do? please correct me..!!

Comment: I think you're saying that if you enter a string that is not exactly in your `morse[]` array, then you get blank output? This would be because that's exactly how your code is written. You only send output if the input string matches something in your `morse[]` array. Are you trying to enter a sequence of morse characters all at once? You need to check one character (dot or dash) of the input at a time against one character (dot or dash) of each morse array entry until a match is found.

Comment: it gives blank output even if i enter the same string as in morse[] array.

Comment: When you `readString` it probably is ending in a line terminator (cr/lf for example) which, of course, won't match what's in your array. You need to trim off the cr/lf.

Comment: but i only enter the "." and "-" as input

Comment: I also print (like this Serial.print(code)) then **code** gives proper output as I entered in serial input

Comment: *but i only enter the "." and "-" as input*... No matter what you type in, when you press "Enter", the "enter" key adds a line terminator to your input string. It won't match what's in your `morse` list of strings. When you print your input, it looks right of course.

Answer (score 1):

what is happening is you are reading the serial buffer in a loop. when you read it it clears the serial buffer so you can't read the same message twice accidentally. so the first time you enter the loops it will work, but the second time code will be empty.

```
  int i = 0;
  code = Serial.readString();
  while (morse[i] != "!")  
  { 
    if (morse[i] == code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but perhaps giving the input via Serial.readString() might add invisible characters such as a linebreak (`\n`) or similar, you could maybe check if there is a linebreak by doing:

```
Serial.print("'" + code + "'");
```

if your output looks something like this:

```
'.-
'
```

instead of this:

```
'.-'
```

there is a linebreak.

perhaps you should move the `code = Serial.readString();` out of the loop, so its right before the loop.

Comment: Means in void setup?